# Viewing vector overlay in an OpenLayers Map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am new to creating maps using HTML and I have been attempting to add two vector layers (places, points) to a base map (roads), however I cannot see the vector layers on the map. The layers should appear as vector overlays to the base map.  The layers are there as they are being shown in the layer switcher, but are not being displayed on screen. I believe the problem is to do with the way the vectors layers are being called. What is the solution to get the vector layers to be displayed. Thanks

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map-id");

    var roads= new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "roads",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
    {layers: "roads"});

var points= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "points",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
    {layers: "points"});

var places= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
    "places",
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
    {layers: "places"});

map.addLayer(roads);
map.addLayer(points);
map.addLayer(places);
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
```

Comment: Do the layers have the same projection as the map?

Comment: All the layers are in the same projection. When the format is changed from new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector to new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS they can be displayed on the map. However, this just makes them base map layers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to display your vector data through WMS protocol. For this purpose you should use OpenLayers.Layer.WMS instances instead OpenLayers.Layer.Vector. For displaying WMS layer as overlay use isBaseLayer option:

```js
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map'); 
var places = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS('places',
  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
  {layers: "places", transparent: true},
  {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 1, singleTile: true, visibility: true}
);
map.addLayers([places]);
```